# Distributing powershell script (.ps1) to computers, from java app on server

Tags: java, powershell, distribution, powershell-2.0

I'm making a Java application which are gonna run on a Windows 2008 R2 server. The applications task is to distribute powershell script files (batch and .ps1) to computers, and maybe other server in the local network(Computers are running Windows XP and Windows Vista, all servers are windows OS). The script is gonna run on each computer and collect hardware/software information to be transfered back to the server.

btw, the script is started by a java program: java executes a batch file which executes a script file.

My questions are:

1. How would i distribute the script?
2. What would be a good way to save the gathered information from each computer to my Windows server?

   - I've tought about saving it to .txt files but it seems like a "extra step" I      don't need, the alternative would probably be to take make the java app collect output from the script.

Alle help will be appreciated!

Comment: I've decided to make a logon script in Powershell, which will gather desired information and then start a java file, which will take the output from powershell as input (in java) and check if the new information is different from what is stored in the local objects. 

If the old objects are different than the new: Enable socket connection to server and transfer objects.

My question this time is, is it possible to get the output from powershell to java, and how?

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit strange that you want to use java for this task. I would use powershell itself for this task. You can just copy the files (assuming you have access to the machines). To execute scripts remotely I usually use psexec from the [pstools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) package.

Comment: I want to make this whole process automated. An admin should be able to press a button "gather info" and things should happen without further intervention.

What do you mean by: "just copy the files" ? I want this to happen without human input other than pressing a button..

Comment: @haakonlu - There is a [copy-cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156818.aspx) in powershell. Depending on the information you want to collect you should also consider collecting it directly from the server (which is possible for a lot of information).

Comment: I've looked into Group Policy and think that will be the right way for me to distribute the script as I already are using GP and Active Directory.

mrab, could you elaborate on collecting information directly from the server(link or something)? Thanks by the way!

Comment: As I don't know what information you'd linke to retrieve it is almost impossible to give a hint or a link. I'd suggest you figure out what information you need and then do a little research (if you don't already know it) how to retrieve it. :-)

Comment: Like i said, hardware and software information for example:
CPU, Graphics card, RAM, OS, Service Pack, username, computer name, computer model, computer manufacturer
That's about it..